# how to get value of dynamically generated label element through jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get text value of dynamically generated label element through jquery .but it is showing blank .how to achieve it any idea would be appreciated.

dynamically generated code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#openForm").click(function () {
            var radioValue = $("input[name='optionsRadios']:checked").val();
            if (radioValue == 'uncoatedRdBtn') {
                $("#pdfForm").prepend("<div id='pdfFormInsideL1'></div>");
                $("#pdfFormInsideL1").prepend("<h3><strong>helm</strong></h3><h3 id='pdfFormInsideL2'><strong> Delivery Conditions (TDC)</strong></h3>")
                $("h3").addClass("text-center");
                $("#pdfFormInsideL2").after("<div id='pdfFormInsideTblRight'></div>");
                $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").addClass("table-responsive pull-right");
                $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").css("width:300px");               
                $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").append("<table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th class='text-center'>TDC No.</th>" +
                        "<th><input id='Tdc_No' type='text' value=''/></th></tr></thead>" +
                        "<tr><td class='text-center'>Revision</td>" +
                        "<td><label id='Revision' value='0'></label></td></tr>" +
                        "<tr><td class='text-center'>Date</td>" +
                        "<td><label id='Revision_Date'></label></td></tr></table>");
                var date = new Date();
                var val = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                $("#Revision_Date").text(val);
 var s = $(' <input type="button" ID="btnFrmSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  value="FrmSubmit"  />');
                $("#btnExport").after(s);
            }

        });

    });        
</script>
```

code through which label value is accessed on clicking 'btnFrmSubmit' button in above script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
            alert("hi");        
            var user = {};
            //user.Product_Id = $("[id*=Product_Id]").val();
            user.Tdcno = $("[id*=Tdc_No]").val();
            user.Revision = $("[id*=Revision]").val();
            user.Revision_Date = $("[id*=Revision_Date]").val();
 user.Created_Date = $("[id*=Revision_Date]").val();
            user.Created_By = $('#form1').find('input[ID="lblUserName"]').val();
</script>
```

Comment: ID should be unique use class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the text value of label by using .text()

```js
var value="Par";
 $("#hId").append('<label id="ID_item">' + value + '</label><br /><hr />');
 $("#hId").on('click','#ID_item', function(){ 
 alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hId"></div>
```

Comment: Look at my req my label is inside table and i want label id='Revision'  value at user.Revision = $("[id*=Revision]").val();
 this position ..